# how to change the .ssh/authorisedKey on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have changed .ssh/ authorisedKey on aws server. After this I have disconnected the terminal. Now when I am trying to login again with new key I am getting authorization failed..Is there any other  way to put the original key without login in to the terminal instance...Can anyone guide me in the right direction ?
thanks

Comment: was it your public ssh key, using which you were sshing into the instance ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to ssh into an Amazon EC2 Linux instance, you can replace the keypair associated with the `ec2-user` with this process:

- **Stop** your EC2 instance
- **Detach** the EBS volume of the instance (remember the device ID, eg `/dev/xvda`)
- **Launch** another EC2 instance ("Debug instance")
- **Attach** the EBS volume to the Debug instance
- **Login** to the Debug instance, access the additonal volume and copy a new keypair to `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (If you're not sure what to copy, copy the file from the same location in the Debug instance.)
- **Unmount** and **detach** the EBS volume from the Debug instance
- **Attach** the EBS volume to the original Instance (eg as `/dev/xvda`)
- **Boot** the original instance and try to login
- **Terminate** the Debug instance

A similar concept is documented here:

- [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)
- [Lost my key with linux authorized_Keys. Now unable to login into the linux](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=217208)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :-
1. Stop your instance.
2. Go to the Actions tab of AWS management console and under instance setting, go to the view/change user data. (attached is the screen shot of same).
3. You can add your ssh key into the user-data of your instance.

```
  #!/bin/bash
your-public-key-content >> <home folder of your user>/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

For example :- my instance is amazon-linux , so below 2 commands form the user-data for me.

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDAbcl5yLq9YUZ6p11eOEUKNyyksdjhfkslfhks amitk" >> /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys .
```

4. Start the instance and try ssh again.

**Edit :- You need to launch instance like this and then include the user-data for the new instance. Thanks Michael - sqlbot for pointing this.**

Comment: by this process my problem solving actually its not my initial launch and my both instance on same device /dev/xvda my other one ssh key changed by this process ??   thanks for reply

Comment: sir this process is not work for me.  why using a dot in last of your example i will not adding it